# Write a query to calculate the even and odd records from a table in postgreSql how can I solve this question

Tags: postgresql

```
EmpID EmpFname EmpLname Department Salary
1      Karan    mehta     HR       300000
2      Rohit    Sharma   Admin      75000
3      Ankush   Rajput  Account     60000
4 Priyadarshini Sharma    HR        500000
5     Sanket    Gupta   Developer   100000
6    Shruthi    Varyar   Admin       80000
7    Rohit      Sharma   Admin       75000
```

Write a query to calculate the even and odd records from a table ?
in PostgreSql

Comment: You mean the modulo operator `%` ? See this example: `SELECT s, s % 2 = 1 as odd FROM generate_series(0,10) g(s);`. But a record will never be even or odd, there is no order in a table, unless you order by something. A value can be even or odd.

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus operator `%`. It returns the remainder from division. `1 % 2` is 1, `2 % 2` is 0, `3 % 2` is 1... so if `x % 2` is true it is odd.

Then you can use a [`case`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) to turn this into 'odd' or 'even'.

```
select
  *,
  case when EmpID % 2 then 'odd' else 'even' end
from Employees
```

Or you can select only the odd rows.

```
select *
from Employees
where EmpID % 2
```

Or the even rows.

```
select *
from Employees
where not EmpID % 2
```